# Instr function in Spark with 3 arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, instr

I have a problem with using `instr()` function in Spark. The definition of function looks like below:
`instr(Column str, String substring)`

I want to use `instr` in the same way as it is in `Impala` like:

`instr(Column str, String substring, Int [position]) - return index position`

In spark we option to give only 2 parameters, but i need to use 3rd parameter with int value basically (-1)

Col has value like

`SNNNN NNNNN NNSNN SNSNS NNNNS`

Expected code:- `instr("ColName", "S", -1)`
Expected result :- `1 0 3 5 5`

Comment: But if you use `instr("ColName", "S", -1)` in impala it will return `29`. I guess you want to get index of first `S` occurence in each part delimited by space? If so, expected output should be 1,0,3,1,5 instead of 1,0,3,5,5 ?

Comment: No, i want output as 1,0,3,5,5 only. in impala if we use in same way it is giving the output as i have mentioned

Comment: Check now, I have added udf. which will give you expected result i.e 1,0,3,5,5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to go with `-ve` position number, `substring_index` + `length` might be helpful as below-

```scala
 val frame = Seq("SNNNN","NNNNN","NNSNN","SNSNS","NNNNS").toDF("values")
    frame.withColumn("x", length($"values") - length(substring_index($"values", "S", -1)))
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +------+---+
      * |values|x  |
      * +------+---+
      * |SNNNN |1  |
      * |NNNNN |0  |
      * |NNSNN |3  |
      * |SNSNS |5  |
      * |NNNNS |5  |
      * +------+---+
      */
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using UDF in spark:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("SNNNN","NNNNN","NNSNN","SNSNS","NNNNS")).toDF("values")
val findIndexUDF = udf( (x: String) => (x.lastIndexOf("S")+1))
df.withColumn("indexval", findIndexUDF($"values")).show()
/*+------+--------+
|values|indexval|
+------+--------+
| SNNNN|       1|
| NNNNN|       0|
| NNSNN|       3|
| SNSNS|       5|
| NNNNS|       5|
+------+--------+*/
```

Comment: the output is not as expected.
expecting output for value: SNSNS should be 5 not 1